# Por que minha consulta não funciona?

Tags: php, mysqli, select

Tenho uma consulta em uma tabela que deveria retornar o valor da quantidade de registros encontrados que atendam a determinado requisito.

**O código:**

```
<?php

    require('conn.php');

    $prevJan= "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS PrevJan FROM participantes WHERE PREVISTO = 'Previsto' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Technique' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D'";
    $realJan= "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS RealJan FROM participantes WHERE REALIZADO = 'Realizado' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Technique' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D'";

    $consultapj = mysqli_query($prevJan);
    $consultarj = mysqli_query($realJan);

    var_dump($consultapj);
?>
```

**A conexão:**

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacao");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

Se eu fizer uma consulta desse jeito pelo phpMyAdmin, ótimo, retorna o valor certinho, porém, se quando eu tento printar o valor na minha página php, printa NULL.

Além disso, quero pegar esse valor e colocar como item de uma lista, veja:

```
data: [<?php echo($consultarj);?>]
```

Alguém tem ideia do que possa estar acontecendo?

Comment: Já viu se no banco realmente existe algum registro que obedece as condições do seu `SELECT` ?

Comment: Já conferi. Eu mesma criei esse banco e conheço de cabo a rabo. Existe. :/

Comment: Pode adicionar o símbolo de porcentagem. `PREVISTO LIKE '%Previsto%'`

Comment: Verifica também se o PHP realmente está fazendo a conexão com o banco, lá n oseu arquivo `conn.php` .

Comment: Então, eu tentei dar um var_dump na conexão, retornou: object(mysqli)#1 (0) { }

Comment: Se você for no seu gerenciador de banco (workbench, phpmyadmin e etc)  e dar o comando `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participantes WHERE PREVISTO = 'Previsto' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Techniques' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D` ele traz alguma coisa ?

Comment: Então, alterando para `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `participantes` WHERE PREVISTO = `Previsto` AND REALIZADO = `Realizado`` Ele me apresenta uma contagem de todos os previstos apenas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `mysqli_query` retorna um objeto **e não o resultado** da query, para pegar o 
`SELECT COUNT(*)` primeiro de um apelido usa [**`AS`** (alias)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html):

```
$prevJan= "SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL FROM participantes WHERE PREVISTO = 'Previsto' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Techniques' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D'";
$consultapj = mysqli_query($prevJan);
```

E então use `fetch_assoc`, assim:

```
$consultapj = mysqli_query($prevJan);

if ($consultapj = mysqli_query($connection, $prevJan)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultapj)) {
        echo 'Total:', $row['TOTAL'];
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($consultapj);
} else {
    die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

**Note** que passei o `$connection` no `mysqli_query`

Se retornar zero (`0`) é porque ou a TABELA é **case-sensitive** ou você errou algo no `WHERE`

---

**[Edição]**

Após a edição da pergunta, a explicação de duas querys é simples, `fetch_array` ou `fetch_assoc` devem de preferencia ficar com suas consultas, na ordem e a variavel `row` não deve ser reaproveitada, pois estamos usando para pegar os resultados dentro do while/if, misturar com outras variáveis pode confundir os resultados:

```
//Variaveis para pegar os resultados
$totaPJ = 0;
$totaRJ = 0;

//qUERYS
$prevJan = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM participantes WHERE PREVISTO = 'Previsto' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Technique' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D'";

$realJan = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM participantes WHERE REALIZADO = 'Realizado' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Technique' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D'";

//Pega o resultado de prevJan
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $prevJan)) {

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $totaPJ = $row['TOTAL']; //Seta o total
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
} else {
    die(mysqli_error($connection));
}

//Pega o resultado de realJan
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $realJan)) {

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $totaRJ = $row['TOTAL']; //Seta o total
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
} else {
    die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

E no gráfico provavelmente vai fazer assim:

```
{
    name: 'Realizado',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [<?php echo $totalRJ; ?>],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    }

}, {
    name: 'Previsto',
    type: 'spline',
    data: [<?php echo $totalPJ; ?>],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarianaFerreira veja se consegue entender a edição da resposta.

Comment: Sim, entendi tudo certinho. Funciona agora, obrigada! :)